# Facebook wall post error from Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have successfully integrated FB with my app.I want to auto post some text,links,images to my facebook wall after giving app permission from facebook account.I have tried using below provided logic but am getting

```
{Response: responseCode: 403,graphObject: null,error: {errorCode: 200,errorType: 
OAuthException,errorMessege: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application
to perform this action}, isFromCache:false
```

FacebookActivity.java

```
public class FacebookActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private MainFragment mainFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
        .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper; 

private Session.StatusCallback callback=new Session.StatusCallback(){
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }

};  

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "Hey I am using this app");
        params.putString("name", "Dexter");
        params.putString("caption", "londatiga.net");
        params.putString("link", "http://www.londatiga.net");
        params.putString("description", "Dexter, seven years old dachshund who loves to catch cats, eat carrot and krupuk");
        params.putString("picture", "http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/6hqd44");

        String uri = "/me/feed?message=" + "Hey I am using this app" + "" + "&access_token=" + session.getAccessToken();

        uri = uri.replace(" ", "%20");

        new Request(

                session,
                uri,
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new Request.Callback() {
                       public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                    ).executeAsync();
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_facebook, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);

    if(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "logged in to FB", 1).show();
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "read_stream"));
        authButton.clearPermissions();
        authButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
    }else{
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

}
```

Comment: Did you get the screen where it ask for Permissions ?

Comment: Previously when i am using this code at that time i am getting app permission .but now its not asking for app permissions. I can't be able to figure out where is the problem.

Comment: go to your facebook account and in settings->apps remove you app permission and try again.

Comment: yup now its asking for app permissions.But,Sir my requirement is after adding app permissions my app should auto post some text ,link etc to my facebook wall.How can i achieve this? Where i have to modify my code?

Comment: There is a simple login app in github-facebook. use it, name changes on successfull login, thats where youshould post your code.

Comment: Sir can you attach here that app link..

Comment: https://github.com/facebookarchive/android-3.0-howtos

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you did not authorize the user with `publish_actions`. Test the Access Token in the Debugger to find out which permissions are authorized: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Btw, you will not get `read_stream` approved in the review process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-read_stream

...meaning, it will only work for Users with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester).

Answer (score 0):

finally after lots of research i have modified my class correctly.Here i am posting my modified code that may help others.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper; 

private Session.StatusCallback callback=new Session.StatusCallback(){
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }

};  

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        publishStory(session);
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}


public void publishStory(Session currentSession) {
     Bundle params = new Bundle();
     params.putString("message", "Hey I am using this app");
        params.putString("name", "Dexter");
        params.putString("caption", "londatiga.net");
        params.putString("link", "http://www.londatiga.net");
        params.putString("description", "Dexter, seven years old dachshund who loves to catch cats, eat carrot and krupuk");
        params.putString("picture", "http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/6hqd44");                                                

     WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),currentSession, params))
       .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

       @Override
       public void onComplete(Bundle values,FacebookException error) {
        if (error == null) {
         // When the story is posted, echo the success
         // and the post Id.
         final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
         if (postId != null) {
             Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);//FacebookActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);
             getActivity().finish();                               // do some stuff
         } else {
         // User clicked the Cancel button
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
           "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
         // User clicked the "x" button
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
          "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
         // Generic, ex: network error
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
          "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
       }

      }).setFrom("").build();
     feedDialog.show();

    }



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_facebook, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);

    if(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "logged in to FB", 1).show();
    }else{
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

}
```